# How to fix : VALIDATION_ERROR: You must also specify a ServiceAccessSecurityGroup Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am new in terraform . I have a issue which I am facing when I am launching a simple EMR cluster in private subnet

It fails with the below error message :

- aws_emr_cluster.emr-test-cluster: [WARN] Error waiting for EMR Cluster state to be "WAITING" or "RUNNING": TERMINATED_WITH_ERRORS: VALIDATION_ERROR: You must also specify a ServiceAccessSecurityGroup if you use custom security groups when creating a cluster in a private subnet.

I did check the github seems like the fixed it for the issue opened . But I am using the latest version of terraform (0.11.7)

Below are the github links for for the issue reported in Github
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/9518
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/9600

Any suggestions on how to fix this will be really helpful

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The issue is fixed in Git because it was raised to show an error which is supposed to ask for `service_access_security_group` while using the `emr_managed_master_security_group` and `emr_managed_slave_security_group`.

So, you would require mentioning `service_access_security_group` parameter in your EMR resource.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I have added the parameter and it works fine now.

Comment: But what is the value of that parameter supposed to be? What rules does the SG need?

Comment: same question, what should be the parameters of the security group ?

Comment: ok i found the response here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-man-sec-groups.html#emr-sg-elasticmapreduce-sa-private

Answer (score 0):

As we know that to put emr components in private subnet, you have to following

these security groups

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-man-sec-groups.html#emr-sg-elasticmapreduce-sa-private

Then in terraform you have to resolve cyclic dependency between security groups from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38246326/cycle-error-when-trying-to-create-aws-vpc-security-groups-using-terraform/38255349#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=Terraform%20attempts%20to%20build%20a,that%20it%20is%20working%20on.&text=Obviously%2C%20your%20example%20is%20going,other%20one%20being%20created%20already.) and put following configuration as shown below

```
 ec2_attributes {
subnet_id                         = element(var.subnet_ids, count.index)
key_name                          = "${var.ssh_key_id}"
emr_managed_master_security_group = aws_security_group.EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup.id
emr_managed_slave_security_group  = aws_security_group.EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup.id
service_access_security_group = aws_security_group.ServiceAccessSecurityGroup.id

#additional_master_security_groups = aws_security_group.allow_ssh.id
instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.example_ec2_profile.arn
}
```

source:- https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/9600